# Backing up my Amazon AMI to an external image

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, external, region, amazon-ami

I'm trying to create an automatic backup of my Amazon AMIs to another region (automatically, of course).

This is possible with the web GUI which Amazon provides, but I couldn't find an API with allows you to do that (I searched both the boto and the rest API).

The only thing that was close or related to this was the boto.*.Image.CopyImage function, but no destination to another region (or even a PasteImage function) exists, so I don't see how it helps me.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initiate copy ami operation from the destination region. In your copy command/api , you have to specify the `source region` where your current ami exist.

Read [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html) carefully. I am quoting the relevant info from the link I referred belo....

> This command is submitted to and initiated from the destination region endpoint.

Comment: This is the exact documentation that will be helpful to you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-CopyImage.html